output messages from threads not appearing
I am trying to get a multithreaded script to work. As I am constrained to use PowerShell 5.1, I am using PowerShell runspaces (as opposed to the -Parallel option to ForEach). I have used the code from this page as my starting point. One thing that I do not understand is why the messages written using Write-Verbose in script block passed to the AddScript method do not appear in the script's output.
For reference, here is the code that I am using:
[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool()
$SessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(
    1, #Min Runspaces
    5 #Max Runspaces
)
$PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
$PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Parameters = @{
    Param1 = 'Param1'
    Param2 = 'Param2'
}

$jobs = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::New()
1..10 | ForEach {
    $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [void]$PowerShell.AddScript(
        {
            Param (
                $Param1,
                $Param2
            )

            $ThreadID = [appdomain]::GetCurrentThreadId()
            Write-Verbose "ThreadID: Beginning $ThreadID" -Verbose
            $Sleep = Get-Random (1..5)
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                Param1 = $Param1
                Param2 = $Param2
                Thread = $ThreadID
                ProcessID = $PID
                SleepTime = $Sleep
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $Sleep
            Write-Verbose "ThreadID: Ending $ThreadID" -Verbose
        })
    [void]$PowerShell.AddParameters($Parameters)
    $Handle = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
    $temp = '' | Select PowerShell,Handle
    $temp.PowerShell = $PowerShell
    $temp.handle = $Handle
    [void]$jobs.Add($Temp)
    Write-Host ("Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: {0}" -f $RunspacePool.GetAvailableRunspaces())
    Write-Host ("Remaining Jobs: {0}" -f @($jobs | Where {
                                                $_.handle.iscompleted -ne 'Completed'
                                            }).Count)
}

# Verify completed
Write-Host ("Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: {0}" -f $RunspacePool.GetAvailableRunspaces())
Write-Host ("Remaining Jobs: {0}" -f @($jobs | Where {
                                            $_.handle.iscompleted -ne 'Completed'
                                        }).Count)

Write-Verbose "Waiting for jobs to finish..." -Verbose
$return = $jobs | ForEach {
    $_.powershell.EndInvoke($_.handle)
    $_.PowerShell.Dispose()
}
Write-Verbose "All jobs have finished" -Verbose

$jobs.Clear()

$return | Group ProcessID | Select Count, Name
$return | Group Thread | Select Count, Name
($return | Group Thread).Count

If I invoke it with the -Verbose command line option (or change Write-Verbose to Write-Host or Write-Output), I do not see any output from within the script argument to the AddScript method. For example:
C:\> .\parallel.ps1


InstanceId               : a965701a-f4d2-45d2-8200-f75fe77d6f72
IsDisposed               : False
RunspacePoolStateInfo    : System.Management.Automation.RunspacePoolStateInfo
InitialSessionState      :
ConnectionInfo           :
CleanupInterval          : 00:15:00
RunspacePoolAvailability : None
ThreadOptions            : Default
ApartmentState           : Unknown

Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 4
Remaining Jobs: 1
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 3
Remaining Jobs: 2
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 2
Remaining Jobs: 3
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 1
Remaining Jobs: 4
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 5
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 6
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 7
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 8
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 9
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 10
Available Runspaces in RunspacePool: 0
Remaining Jobs: 10
VERBOSE: Waiting for jobs to finish...
VERBOSE: All jobs have finished
Count : 10
Name  : 5400

Count : 2
Name  : 14208

Count : 3
Name  : 7708

Count : 2
Name  : 13584

Count : 1
Name  : 1940

Count : 2
Name  : 17756

5

Why is this so?

I suggest you have a look at this module: https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline it can do the same as ForEach-Object -Parallel and is compatible with pwsh 5.1

You can set up event registrations for the streams you want to forward on each [powershell] instance:
1..10 | ForEach {
    $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [void]$PowerShell.AddScript(
        {
            Param (
                $Param1,
                $Param2
            )

            $ThreadID = [appdomain]::GetCurrentThreadId()
            Write-Verbose "ThreadID: Beginning $ThreadID" -Verbose
            $Sleep = Get-Random (1..5)
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                Param1 = $Param1
                Param2 = $Param2
                Thread = $ThreadID
                ProcessID = $PID
                SleepTime = $Sleep
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $Sleep
            Write-Verbose "ThreadID: Ending $ThreadID" -Verbose
        })
    [void]$PowerShell.AddParameters($Parameters)

    # subscribe to event DataAdded on verbose stream
    $eventRegistration = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $PowerShell.Streams.Verbose -EventName DataAdded -Action {
        param($s,$e)

        # re-emit verbose message in default runspace
        $s[$e.Index] |Write-Verbose
    }
    
    [void]$jobs.Add($(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            PowerShell = $PowerShell
            EventIdentifier = $eventRegistration.Name
            Handle = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
        }
    ))
}

Then add an extra cleanup step for the event subscription:
$return = $jobs | ForEach {
    $_.PowerShell.EndInvoke($_.Handle)
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.EventIdentifier
    $_.PowerShell.Dispose()
}


@SantiagoSquarzon you'd obviously have to set $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' or call the invoking script with -Verbose :)

One easy option to see the verbose output as well as other streams (except for Success and Error) as they're generated, you can hook your PSHost to the RunspacePool:
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5, $Host)

The downside of using this approach is that the output goes straight the the host, it cannot be captured.
The other alternative is when ending the invocations you can get each output stream by looking at the .Streams property, downside is that the output isn't real time.
$jobs | ForEach-Object {
    $_.PowerShell.Streams.Error | Write-Error
    $_.PowerShell.Streams.Verbose | Write-Verbose -Verbose
    $_.PowerShell.Streams.Warning | Write-Warning
    # and other streams here...
    $_.PowerShell.EndInvoke($_.Handle)
    $_.PowerShell.Dispose()
}

If you need streaming output from your threads there are other alternatives however those get increasingly more complicated in PowerShell. I suggest you have a look at the ThreadJob Module or, if you want something more similar to ForEach-Object -Parallel you can checkout PSParallelPipeline Module.
